# Online OCR website for processing an entire pdf file at one time?

Tags: ocr

I am looking for an online OCR website for processing a multi-page pdf file at one time. Free preferably.

I know http://www.newocr.com/. If I am correct, it can only OCR one page at a time, by manually clicking "Preview" and then clicking "OCR" for each page. After each page is OCRed, I have to copy out the text result manually too.

If my pdf file has 30~ pages, it will be tedious to repeat the above process for each page. I wonder if there is some other online websites that OCR a whole pdf file, without asking me for manual operation?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions about online services are a better fit for [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com). I would have voted to migrate, but there's already [Are there any online OCR services?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/484/are-there-any-online-ocr-services).

Comment: You can convert the first 30 pages of a document with [Free Online OCR](http://www.free-online-ocr.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Docs can OCR PDFs but you need to upload your PDF to Google Drive for that to work.

The process is explained [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/176692?hl=en). Simply right-click your PDF file in the Google Drive website and select *Open with* / *Google Docs* from the context menu. The formatting will not be retained very well, however.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [this](http://www.cvisiontech.com/online-conversion/general/main.html) free online tool for OCR'ing multi-page PDF files:

Comment: Nice page, and it converts long documents too (at leas my 184 page pdf)! Although it did at a watermark in the footer, which could be undesired in some cases.